# Удалить из списка все уникальные элементы с шагом 2 и предшествующий уникальному элемент Python

Tags: python, list

Есть список `list1 = [1, [], 2, [1, 2], 3, [1, 2], 4, [3, 4, 5], 5, [], 6, [1, 2], 7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 8, [1]]`, нужно удалить из списка все уникальные элементы начиная с `list1[1]` с шагом 2 + предшествующий уникальному элемент. Т.е. должен получиться список `list2 = [1, [], 2, [1, 2], 3, [1, 2], 5, [], 6, [1, 2]]`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быстро это сделать на python, может есть какие-нибудь функции в библиотеках?

Comment: По-моему в ```list2``` есть лишние элементы, например *1*

Comment: по-моему это вопрос из разряда ["Как правильно держать микроскоп?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) Все модули, которые значительно ускоряют работу с векторами и матрицами (Numpy, Pandas, sympy, etc.) работают со структурами одинаковой размерности - т.е. если это 2D матрица, то она должна состоять из строк __одинаковой__ длины.

Comment: Вы можете значительно улучшить ваш вопрос, прояснив изначальную проблему - как и зачем вы получили эти данные и что вы планируете с ними делать?

Comment: Элемент 1 уникален, но не удалён. Элемент 2 уникален,  но не удалён. Элемент 3 уникален, но не удалён. И т.д. Разберитесь сначала, что вам нужно, и потом опишите это так, чтобы не было противоречий между описанием и желаемым результатом.

Comment: @Nobody, нет, они не лишние. Мне нужно убрать уникальные элементы начиная с list1[1] с шагом два, только их проверять на уникальность. И если он вдруг уникален, то удалить его и удалить предшествующий ему элемент

Comment: ну тогда добавьте это условие в вопрос, иначе смыл другой получается и путаница

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
list1 = ... # консоль или сразу задается
list2 = list1.copy()
i = 1
while(i <= len(list1)):
    if list1.count(list1[i]) == 1:
        list2.remove(list2[i])
        list2.remove(list2[i-1])
        i += 2
print(list2)
```

Comment: Да, почти верно, спасибо большое. Не хватает i += 2 и если делать list2 = list1, то любые изменения в list1 ведут к изменениям в list2 => пробегает не по всему списку. Но это всё получилось исправить, так что спасибо!!!

Comment: Задумался, когда писал. Все исправил)